# Allow Dropzone js to upload only zip files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dropzone.js

In my mvc net core app I need to implement drag&drop files uploader. I found Dropzone js and hoping to use it in my purposes. But can't configure it, I need to allow it upload ony zip files.
My code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div id="dropzone">
            <form action="/Home/Upload" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="uploader">
                <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                    Drop files here or click to upload.<br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        Dropzone.options.uploader = {
            paramName: "file",
            maxFilesize: 256,
            acceptedFiles: "application/zip,application/octet-stream,application/x-zip-compressed,multipart/x-zip,.zip",
            maxFiles: 1
        };

});
</script>
```

Also of course I have controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Uploads");
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But still, application allows to upload any file with any MIME type. Where is a problem?
Also restriction of maxFiles isn't working too - it allows me to upload infinite count of files.

Comment: Which version DropzoneJs my friend?

Comment: @Tomato32 latest version from gitlab : https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/builds/artifacts/master/download?job=release

Answer (score 4):

You can use option of dropzone.js name acceptedfile.

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
 ....
acceptedFiles: ".zip",
....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration), you can do it like this:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  accept: function(file, done) {
    if (file.name.endsWith !== ".zip") {
      done("Naha, you don't.");
    }
    else { done(); }
  }
};
```

> A function that gets a file and a done function as parameters. If the
>   done function is invoked without arguments, the file is "accepted" and
>   will be processed. If you pass an error message, the file is rejected,
>   and the error message will be displayed. This function will not be
>   called if the file is too big or doesn't match the mime types.

Edit:
Here is a fiddle to demonstrate it: http://jsfiddle.net/behyzjng/15/

Comment: Nope, somehow this is still upload everything :(

Comment: I don't really know how to debug JS in visual studio (oopsie), so I can only debug backend side (controller home/upload method).. Ho do I can debug this part of code?  Sorry for that type of question

Comment: In the browser. Press f12, go to your js file, set a breakpoint and you're good to go.

Comment: I does what you've written, it never stops in my code from <script> $(document).ready(function () { in my cshtml file ... I don't understand why.  probably I have added this code in wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Set `acceptedFiles: 'application/zip'` in `defaultOptions`

Here are the documentation for you to work on `Dropzone.js`:

- Github:  https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone
- Docs:    https://docs.dropzone.dev
- check all avaliable options at https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/src/options.js
- check the desired extensions allowed and write the MIME type as a value of acceptedFiles at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Working solution here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@5/dist/min/dropzone.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        .my-dropzone {
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100px; 
            border: 1px dashed; 
            display: flex; 
            align-items: center; 
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="my-dropzone">
        Drag and drop zip files here, or click here to upload.
    </div>

    <script>
        // Dropzone.js
        // Github:  https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone
        // Docs:    https://docs.dropzone.dev

        // check all avaliable options at
        // https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/src/options.js
        const defaultOptions = { 
            url: "/file/post",
            // check the desired extensions allowed and write the MIME type as a value of acceptedFiles at
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types
            acceptedFiles: 'application/zip'
        };

        // Dropzone has been added as a global variable.
        const dropzone = new Dropzone("div.my-dropzone", defaultOptions);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```